# Does each validator have equal voting right in a committee?

Tags: proof-of-stake, validators, voting

I am very new to Ethereum.

I am wondering once validators are selected for a committee, does every validator have equal voting right? Or their voting rights are weighted by their deposit balances? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all attestations (votes) by validators are equal.

Each validator needs a deposit of 32 ETH.  There is little benefit to depositing more than 32 ETH for 1 validator.  For example, if you have 64 ETH, it's more beneficial to run 2 validators.